# C++ Cstring split

Tags: c++, split

Can you help me to get last word in `CString`?

```
string[] tokens = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');

lastword = ConvertToDouble(tokens[tokens.Length - 1]);
```

I have this is C# but I need it in C++ Windows Desktop Application. 
Edit: I said word, but I will split numbers

Comment: note that c-strings and `Cstring` are not the same. I dont really know what you are talking about (because I dont know `CString` nor C#) but I thing the `c-string` tag is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CString::ReverseFind()` to find the last space and then use `CString::Mid()` to get that last substring.

```
CString str;
.. str.ReverseFind(' '); // check result for >= 0
str.Mid(..);
```

Comment: This does extra the last word, but it doesn't split the string, which was alluded to in the tags.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It looks like the tags (and title) are inconsistent with the actual question "'Can you help me to get last word in CString?" (or maybe OP meant to 'split' before the last word/number)

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to splitting `CString`s. I opted for this flexible approach to convert it into a `CStringArray` in my project:

```cpp
// breaks the string down into its delimiters (seperated by zChar)
BOOL CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SplitString(CString strText,
                                               UINT uNumSegments,
                                               CStringArray &rAryStrSegments,
                                               TCHAR zChar)
{
    BOOL    bOK = TRUE;
    CString strSegment;
    UINT    uSegment, uCount = 0;
    int     iStartIndex, iFindIndex;

    rAryStrSegments.RemoveAll();

    if (uNumSegments == (UINT)-1)
    {
        // we must work out how many segments their are
        iStartIndex = 0;
        iFindIndex = strText.Find(zChar, iStartIndex);
        while (iFindIndex != -1)
        {
            uCount++;
            iStartIndex = iFindIndex + 1;
            iFindIndex = strText.Find(zChar, iStartIndex);
        }
        uNumSegments = uCount + 1;      // I think.. :)
    }

    uSegment = 1;
    iStartIndex = 0;
    while (uSegment <= uNumSegments)
    {
        if (uSegment < uNumSegments)
        {
            iFindIndex = strText.Find(zChar, iStartIndex);
            if (iFindIndex == -1)
            {
                // oops, incorrect number of zChar in this string
                bOK = FALSE;
                break;
            }

            strSegment = strText.Mid(iStartIndex, iFindIndex - iStartIndex);
            iStartIndex = iFindIndex + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // no more zChar should exist now
            iFindIndex = strText.Find(zChar, iStartIndex);
            if (iFindIndex != -1)
            {
                // oops - more zChar exist
                bOK = FALSE;
                break;
            }

            strSegment = strText.Mid(iStartIndex);
        }

        // Handle empty strings
        if (strSegment.IsEmpty())
            strSegment = _T(" ");

        rAryStrSegments.Add(strSegment);
        uSegment++;
    }

    return bOK;
}
```

Then you can extract the last item in the `CStringArray`.

As mentioned, there are several ways to "get the last word". But you have tagged it `split`. Hope this helps!